# What is the behavior of running threads started by java.util.Timer when Timer.cancel() is called?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-6

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

The reason for this question is that I have a timer running at one-minute intervals which makes a network request that sometimes takes up to 5 seconds to resolve, and then writes to a file on disk.

When the application is terminated, I need to clean up the file handlers, but I don't want to do that if the timer-initiated thread is in currently blocked on a network call, and may attempt to write to a closed file handler later.

It's hard to test deterministically what happens when `Timer.stop()` is called at an arbitrary point in time, so I'm hoping that someone who either works on Java or has solved a similar problem might be able to help.

Comment: Just to clarify the scope of the problem, I might have multiple timers doing the same thing, which will all have to deal with this problem.

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.Timer#cancel()` instead of `#stop()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your update, it appears you mean Timer.cancel which explains what it does.

```
/**
 * Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.
 * Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists).
 * Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates
 * gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.
 *
 * <p>Note that calling this method from within the run method of a
 * timer task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that
 * the ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever
 * be performed by this timer.
 *
 * <p>This method may be called repeatedly; the second and subsequent
 * calls have no effect.
 */
public void cancel() {
    synchronized(queue) {
        thread.newTasksMayBeScheduled = false;
        queue.clear();
        queue.notify();  // In case queue was already empty.
    }
}
```

---

I assume you mean `javax.swing.Timer` as `java.util.Timer` doesn't have a stop() method, and `javax.management.timer.Timer` and `sun.misc.Timer` (have stop() methods but are rather obscure)

AFAIK, Its a very bad idea to use this timer for IO as it uses the GUI thread and can cause it to lock up for periods of time.

Looking at the code

```
/**
 * Stops the <code>Timer</code>,
 * causing it to stop sending action events
 * to its listeners.
 *
 * @see #start
 */
public void stop() {
    getLock().lock();
    try {
        cancelEvent();
        timerQueue().removeTimer(this);
    } finally {
        getLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

You can see it stop sending new tasks, but does interrupt or stop() running ones.

Comment: Please see my revision. I was referencing the documentation for the wrong timer, when I wrote the question, but the timer I'm actually using is the one in java.util.

Comment: My application is a console app, using java.util.Timer.

Comment: As I pointed out java.util.Timer has no `stop()` method, can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Timer in daemon mode? Please see this documentation which says what's a daemon thread.

```
/**
 * Creates a new timer whose associated thread may be specified to
 * {@linkplain Thread#setDaemon run as a daemon}.
 * A daemon thread is called for if the timer will be used to
 * schedule repeating "maintenance activities", which must be
 * performed as long as the application is running, but should not
 * prolong the lifetime of the application.
 *
 * @param isDaemon true if the associated thread should run as a daemon.
 */
public Timer(boolean isDaemon) {
    this("Timer-" + serialNumber(), isDaemon);
}
```

If you are using a daemon thread, application will not wait for this thread to finish so any pending operation in this thread is not guaranteed to finish. However, if it's not a daemon thread, the application will shutdown only after this thread finishes its last operation.

Coming to the closing of file handles, why don't you do that in the timer thread itself? If that cannot be done, Shudown hooks are the ideal way to do something at the application shutting down time.

So, you can have a common lock, which can be acquired by the timer for every task execution and the same lock can be acquired by the shutdown task to close the open file handles.

I hope that makes things clear.